# Limit association query via Shopware 6 Admin API

Tags: vue.js, shopware6

I want to fetch layouts together with the categories, products, ... they are assigned to.

This can be done by adding an association to a query on the pagerepository (`this.repositoryFactory.create('cms_page');`)

```js
const criteria = new Criteria(this.page, this.limit);
criteria.addAssociation('categories');
```

in the [listCriteria](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5ef505881c2559e4a49d96368ec1a7811aa0beb5/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/page/sw-cms-list/index.js#L97) method.

There might be many matches, so I want to get only the first 5 associated entities.

I tried

```js
criteria.addAssociation('categories').setLimit(5);
```

But that would limit the full query.

How can I fine-tune this associated query?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out after posting:

This works after adding the association:

```
criteria.getAssociation('categories').setLimit(5);
```

EDIT: Even this single line is enough: The association does not need to be added first. `getAssociation()` does this implicitly.